# How to fix: USB mouse settings restored to default on each connection?

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, xinput

I'm connecting and disconnecting `USB mouse` from the notebook. I've noticed that every time default `xinput` settings is restored, precisely `Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271): 10.000000` which drives me mad - mouse is way too fast.

I've found out that:

1. `xinput` told me what `device_id` has my mouse,
2. `xinput list-props [device_id]` contained source of my problem,
3. and `xinput set-prop [device_id] [prop_id] [value]` changed the mouse speed to acceptable experience.

How to run that last `command` on each `USB mouse` connection or even better - make the setting permanent?

---

For now I'm using following command:

```
xinput set-prop 'pointer:MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse' 'Device Accel Velocity Scaling' 4
```

I have to use `string mouse id` (words) instead of numeric because on every disconnection that can change, same for `prop id`. Also `pointer:` prefix because the mouse apparently shows its' special keys as a keyboard and could not be identified by string otherwise.

Comment: Same issue here and it's even worse: The setting falls back every now and then - even while I use the mouse.